# Letsencrypt - Change installed certificates to use --webroot for renewal instead of --standalone

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I have already set up certificates using the --standalone flag which is working great but the problem is I have to stop Nginx server every time I have to renew the certificates because the --standalone option requires port 80 to be free.

The --webroot method does not require stopping the server and essentially taking down all the sites on the server.

So is it possible to renew certificates using --webroot which were installed using the --standalone flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up also asking the same question on [Letsencrypt forums](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/renew-a-cert-with-webroot-plugin-which-was-generated-with-standalone-plugin/12357/4?u=nik) where I got an answer.

Basically, when you have created certificate with `--standalone` plugin, just regenerate it with `--webroot` and then it can be updated with `--webroot` from next time onwards.

`sudo ./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot --renew-by-default -w <your-site-directory> -d <your-site>`